# CASE returns multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to determine whether a computer in our organization has certain applications assigned to it.  The problem I'm having is that the left join is listing duplicates, listing out every assignment rather than ideally listing the computer name, then 1 if the app(s) is assinged to it or 0 if it doesn't have any of those apps assigned to it.  What approach should I take to accomplish this?

The app list can have up to 100+ applications so I need to use an IN.  I am unable to modify any of the DB columns.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5a387/5

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
  CREATE TABLE macs
    (`wsid` int, `mach_name` varchar(20))
;
CREATE TABLE assignments
    (`wsid` int, `adp_id` int)
;
INSERT INTO macs
    (`wsid`, `mach_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'computer1'),
    (2, 'computer2'),
    (3, 'computer3')
;
INSERT INTO assignments
    (`wsid`, `adp_id`)
VALUES
    (1, '100'),
    (1, '101'),
    (1, '103'),
    (2, '100'),
    (2, '101'),
    (3, '100'),
    (3, '101'),
    (3, '103')
     ;
```

and the query:

```
select mach_name,
CASE
   WHEN b.adp_id in(103) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
from macs a
left join assignments b on a.wsid = b.wsid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `exists`:

```
select m.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from assignments a where a.wsid = w.wsid and a.adp_id in (103)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as flag
from macs m;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a correlated sub-query,

```sql
SELECT mach_name, COALESCE((SELECT 1 FROM assignments WHERE wsid=m.wsid AND adp_id=103 LIMIT 1), 0) FROM macs m
```

then `COALESCE` the potentially `NULL` value to `0`. This is a bit more compact than a `CASE` statement.

The reason that the `OUTER JOIN` is returning multiple rows is because rows on the left side of the `JOIN` can occur multiple times in the right hand side. I.e. there is only one of each machine, but machines can have many assignments. So there are multiple rows that contain a given machine which satisfy your join predicate.

Both the `CASE` answer and my answer select from the `macs` table once, and select the result into a column for each machine.